# Randomly swap the positions of 4 UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have 4 UIButtons, positioned in my VC.  I want to randomly swap the positions of each button.  I've placed all of the UIButton positions into a NSMutableArray

```
self.frameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.frameArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(60,171,64,64)]];
[self.frameArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(198,171,64,64)]];
[self.frameArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(60,333,64,64)]];
[self.frameArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(198,333,64,64)]];
```

`

and all of my buttons are in a NSArray

```
self.buttons = @[self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4];
```

but i'm really not sure where to go from here, to make the positions of the UIButtons to randomly swap.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So your goal is basically to assign 1 of 4 frameArarys to 1 of the buttons in self.buttons without repeating coordinates correct?

Comment: yes that is it, want all of the buttons in self.buttons to have random .frame from frameArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to create the frameArray then randomize the order of the frames and then apply them to the buttons.

**Step One:** Randomize the frameArray (place code after creation of frameArray)

```
NSUInteger count = [self.frameArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSInteger remainingCount = count - i;
    NSInteger exchangeIndex = i + arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t )remainingCount);
    [self.frameArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:exchangeIndex];
}
```

**Step Two:** Set Button Frames

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.buttons count]; i++) {
    [[self.buttons objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:[self.frameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at [[self.buttons objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:[self.frameArray objectAtIndex:i]];  error: parameter of incompatible type CGRect.  Have I set up my frameArray wrong maybe?

Comment: it builds with  [[self.buttons objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:[((NSValue *)[self.frameArray objectAtIndex:i]) CGRectValue]];   But all of the buttons disappear? is it the way i'm setting the frame maybe?

Comment: works great, I wasn't creating frames in the correct place.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use arc4random_uniform() to get a random button and a random Rect from the arrays, and then assign the random Rect to the random button's frame:

```
NSInteger randomButton = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.buttons.count);
NSInteger randomRect = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.frameArray.count);

UIButton *button = self.buttons[randomButton];
NSValue *theRectValue = self.frameArray[randomRect];
CGRect rect = [theRectValue CGRectValue];

button.frame = rect;
```

I think this will work.

Comment: I'm getting an error and a warning. warning for 'NSUInteger randomRect = arc4random_uniform(self.frameArray.count); error:implicit conversion'     And error for CGRect rect = self.frameArray[randomRect]; error:initialising CGRect with an expression of incompatible type